# Using a COM .dll from Java without registering the library using regsvr32

Tags: java, dll, com, java-native-interface, jna

I have a COM DLL which describes several versions of an interface. This DLL also relies on 2 other regular DLL files as dependencies (that is my guess, I have those 2 DLLs as well).

Using COM/OLE browser, that comes with Visual C++, I was able to generate .IDL file, so I know what methods are there in the interfaces.

I can't understand how to create a java object delegating to the methods in the COM DLL without registering the DLL with regsvr32. I also don't know how should the 'other DLLs' dependencies be resolved in this case.

I've tried reading about com4j, JACOB, etc., but everything I've found was focused on Word/Excel/PowerPoint/Outlook automation using their COM interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used JAVOB (or any other Java -> COM Bridge for that matter) but I'd expect that using the Office automation objects should be no different than using any other COM component.

One possible difference is related to how you'll access the components (early/late binding, or, Custom interface or Dispatch interface).

If I were in your position, I'd first try to register / access the component (using either JACOB, com4j or any other COM bridge for Java). Only after getting this scenario to work I'd move to the next step: trying to get rid of the requirement to register the COM dll (check the [registration free COM activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx) - it may work).

If you fail to access the component after registering the dll you may still try to use other languages (for example C# or VB.NET, VB 6, Delphi, C++, etc) with easier COM integration to test your registration.

More info about [registration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1h056h(v=vs.110).aspx) [free](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx) [COM activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f8h7012w(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I've already tried using C# - everything works if I register the dll. I couldn't get it tow work without registration with C# though, as I don't know enough about COM and C#.

Comment: I'm trying to follow that tutorial now, getting strange errors from MSVS 2013, but StackOverflow helps :)

Comment: I've edited the answer and included some more links to registration free COM (some specific to .Net)

Comment: Thanks! I'm fighting with C++ solution from your first link for now :)